# angularjs ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-click

привет проблема с обработкой нажатия

```
<div class="col-md-9 container-body" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="divider-parent">
            <h1 ng-click="al()">главная</h1>
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </div>
</div>


var MainModule = angular.module('MainModule', []);

    MainModule.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.items = array;

        $scope.al = function(){
            alert('dd');
        }
    });
```

Все как на офф сайте сделано но не рабит чета(

Comment: нет `ng-app`...

Comment: она есть у меня же коллекция  $scope.items = array работает

Comment: если ng-app есть, то приведенный кусок кода вполне рабочий. сделай [mcve] чтобы воспроизвести проблему